# amova with poppr R package

Tags: r

I want to run an amova withthe poppr package in R and am having difficulty understanding the results. The code I use here is based on the package documentation https://grunwaldlab.github.io/poppr/reference/poppr.amova.html and the example data included. My allele frequency data include  280 samples across 28 populations. The library example includes both population and subpopulation strata, so I want to try an amova on the example data using just one stratification. To do this I used interaction of population and subpopulation (called Pop_Subpop, since there were only 2 populations in the example). Below I've annotated code that first runs an example with population and subpopulation groups, and  then try a second amova on Pop_Subpop which will be more similar to my data. The problem is that I am not sure what the reported tests statistics and significance are indicating, especially for the amova on Pop_Subpop. I tried looking through the poppr and ade4 documentation for any further explanation but couldn't find answers to my questions. Below is the code I ran on the poppr  package example data:

```
    > library(poppr)
Loading required package: adegenet
Loading required package: ade4

   /// adegenet 2.1.10 is loaded ////////////

   > overview: '?adegenet'
   > tutorials/doc/questions: 'adegenetWeb()' 
   > bug reports/feature requests: adegenetIssues()


Registered S3 method overwritten by 'pegas':
  method      from
  print.amova ade4
This is poppr version 2.9.4. To get started, type package?poppr
OMP parallel support: available
> 
> # load test data and inspect
> data(Aeut)
> Aeut
/// GENIND OBJECT /////////

 // 187 individuals; 56 loci; 56 alleles; size: 68.9 Kb

 // Basic content
   @tab:  187 x 56 matrix of allele counts
   @loc.n.all: number of alleles per locus (range: 56-56)
   @ploidy: ploidy of each individual  (range: 2-2)
   @type:  PA
   @call: old2new_genind(object = x, donor = new(class(x)))

 // Optional content
   @pop: population of each individual (group size range: 90-97)
   @other: a list containing: population_hierarchy 

> 
> # assign pop and subpop to strata
> strata(Aeut) <- other(Aeut)$population_hierarchy
> other(Aeut) <- other(Aeut)$population_hierarchy
> 
> # convert to genclone
> agc <- as.genclone(Aeut)
> agc

This is a genclone object
-------------------------
Genotype information:

   119 original multilocus genotypes 
   187 diploid individuals
    56 dominant loci

Population information:

     3 strata - Pop_Subpop, Pop, Subpop
     2 populations defined - Athena, Mt. Vernon
> 
> #run amova 
> amova.result <- poppr.amova(agc, ~Pop/Subpop)

 No missing values detected.

> amova.result #highest variation is between pop
$call
ade4::amova(samples = xtab, distances = xdist, structures = xstruct)

$results
                            Df    Sum Sq     Mean Sq
Between Pop                  1 1051.2345 1051.234516
Between samples Within Pop  16  273.4575   17.091091
Within samples             169  576.5059    3.411277
Total                      186 1901.1979   10.221494

$componentsofcovariance
                                           Sigma          %
Variations  Between Pop                11.063446  70.006786
Variations  Between samples Within Pop  1.328667   8.407483
Variations  Within samples              3.411277  21.585732
Total variations                       15.803391 100.000000

$statphi
                        Phi
Phi-samples-total 0.7841427
Phi-samples-Pop   0.2803128
Phi-Pop-total     0.7000679

> 
> # Test for significance
> amova.test <- randtest(amova.result)
> plot(amova.test)
> amova.test # are significant- more covariacne than expected between samples and pops, less within samples?
class: krandtest lightkrandtest 
Monte-Carlo tests
Call: randtest.amova(xtest = amova.result)

Number of tests:   3 

Adjustment method for multiple comparisons:   none 
Permutation number:   99 
                        Test       Obs   Std.Obs   Alter Pvalue
1  Variations within samples  3.411277 -35.12472    less   0.01
2 Variations between samples  1.328667  19.83446 greater   0.01
3     Variations between Pop 11.063446  11.00859 greater   0.01

> 
> # but I want to try with only the population level, since my real data has samples within pops and no subpop structure
> 
> # to do this I can  run on the amova on the 18 uniqpe Pop x Subpop groups (Pop_Subpop) present in the strata list
> 
> # run amova code on this
> amova.result <- poppr.amova(agc, ~Pop_Subpop)

 No missing values detected.

> amova.result # more variation between samples than within- does between samples mean between groups/pops?
$call
ade4::amova(samples = xtab, distances = xdist, structures = xstruct)

$results
                 Df    Sum Sq   Mean Sq
Between samples  17 1324.6920 77.923057
Within samples  169  576.5059  3.411277
Total           186 1901.1979 10.221494

$componentsofcovariance
                                Sigma         %
Variations  Between samples  7.201099  67.85567
Variations  Within samples   3.411277  32.14433
Total variations            10.612376 100.00000

$statphi
                        Phi
Phi-samples-total 0.6785567

> amova.test <- randtest(amova.result)
> plot(amova.test)
> amova.test # what does this mean?
Monte-Carlo test
Call: as.randtest(sim = res, obs = sigma[1])

Observation: 7.201099 

Based on 99 replicates
Simulated p-value: 0.01 
Alternative hypothesis: greater 

    Std.Obs Expectation    Variance 
30.15800227  0.02029495  0.05669451
```

My questions are:

1. What is the Phi calculation in amova.result? In the second call of amova.result, the example using with Pop_Subgroup, I am not sure if the "Phi-samples-total" of 0.6785567 is comparing between populations or between all samples regardless of population.
2. What are the results of the amova.test call comparing- in the second call of amova.test, again the example using with Pop_Subgroup, is this comparing between populations or samples?

Thanks in advance for any insight into these questions or other suggestions for running an amova.

Answer (score 0):

After some more digging I was able to find answers to my questions. The output of this test refers to groups (populations in this case) as samples. So, the components of covariance reported in amova.result are the within and between components of covariance, and the Monte Carlo test in amova.test reports that the between sample (aka population) covariance is significantly greater than expected.

The step by step tutorial [here](https://grunwaldlab.github.io/Population_Genetics_in_R/AMOVA.html) and post reply [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Difference-between-among-vs-within-individuals-in-an-AMOVA-analysis) were very helpful.